# Is there any way to obtain features of any layer from autoencoder in Keras?

Tags: keras, computer-vision, conv-neural-network, autoencoder, semantic-segmentation

Hi Guys I am working with autoencoders, I am trying to get the features from a specific layer of autoencoder ( I am not interested in the latent space). I am using the following code:

```
#Define autoencoder
import keras 
input_shape  = (1, 512, 512, 1)
SIZE = 512


encoder = keras.models.Sequential()
encoder.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (9, 9), activation='elu', padding='same', input_shape=(SIZE, SIZE, 1)))
encoder.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())


encoder.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (7, 7), activation='elu', padding='same'))
encoder.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())


encoder.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='elu', padding='same'))
encoder.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
encoder.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())



encoder.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same'))
encoder.add(keras.layers.MaxPooling2D((2, 2), padding='same'))
encoder.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())


#Decoder
decoder = keras.models.Sequential()

decoder.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same'))
decoder.add(keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
decoder.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())


decoder.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (5, 5), activation='elu', padding='same'))
decoder.add(keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
decoder.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())


decoder.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (7, 7), activation='elu', padding='same'))
#decoder.add(keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
decoder.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())



decoder.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(32, (9,9), activation='elu', padding='same'))
#decoder.add(keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
decoder.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())



#decoder.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(64, (11,11), activation='elu', padding='same'))
#decoder.add(keras.layers.UpSampling2D((2, 2)))
#decoder.add(keras.layers.BatchNormalization())


decoder.add(keras.layers.Conv2D(1, (3, 3), activation='elu', padding='same'))

autoencoder = keras.models.Sequential([encoder,decoder])

autoencoder.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer = "adam")
autoencoder.summary()
```

Finally, I train the autoencoder:

```
model_train = autoencoder.fit(X_train_noise, X_train,
        epochs=5000,
        shuffle=True)
```

Now, I need to enter a new image but I only want the outputs from the third layer from the encoder part of the defined CNN. Any ideas?

Thanks!!!

Comment: This has been asked hundreds of times here, put some search before asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Sequential model you can get any layer output by the `model.layers[index]` or `model.get_layer(layer_name)`.

For example for the third layer output:

```
features_for_third_layer = encoder.layers[2].output
```

or

```
features_for_third_layer = autoencoder.layers[0].layers[2].output
```

---

After training autoencoder, if you want just the output of any arbitrary layer of encoder, and you want to feed an image and get the output, one easy way is to define another model like this:

```
new_model = keras.models.Model(inputs=encoder.input, outputs=encoder.layers[2].output)
```

Then, you can get the output like this:

```
feature_vector = new_model.predict([image])
```